# Why is the water pressure in my home clearly less than my neighbors?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

I own a relatively new home (3 years old) in a new development.  I have a PEX water system, which I love (as do all my neighbors).

So, I put out the "fan" sprinkler in my yard, and it shoots an anemic four feet high.  My neighbors fan sprinklers shoot a robust 15 feet or more.

I notice that in general, the water pressure in my house is less than I'd like it.

Is there something going on?  What can I do to improve my water pressure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look for something like this.
[image: pressure reducing valve]
near or on the water meter.  This is a pressure reducing valve, and it's used by some municipalities to control the pressure entering to house.  They are adjustable, so the one in your house might be set too low.

If you have a manifold setup on the PEX system, check to make sure the shutoffs on the manifold are fully open. You can also check the main shutoff for the house, to make sure it is fully open.

If you still cannot get better pressure, you might try calling the municipality and asking them for help. It could be a problem with the system before it enters your home.

*This answer assumes you are using city water, if you use well or another water source there may be more things to check.*

Comment: +1 - if it is not the valve you are covered by a new builds warranty- and in terms of pipes you should be covered up to 10 years for any costs of repairs as stated in most Home Building Regulations and its the responsibility of the contractors to fix it.

Comment: This was exactly it. The picture was very helpful -- that's exactly what I had in my basement.   A few cranks on the top bolt, and I no longer have "Sprinkler Envy".  ;-)  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

Check the main shutoff valve, where the water comes in the house; it may be partially closed; close it, then open again.  Also check the screen on the hose, it may be full of gunk. You may have a faulty pressure regulator, you can check your pressure easily with an inexpensive [gauge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004RACK)