# Low water pressure in house

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

My inside water pressure is very low.  My outside pressure is good.  I did disconnect an old water softener and just connected the input and output pipes from the softener together.  I would like to fix the problem myself without calling a plumber...Any ideas???

Comment: What is the difference in pressure from outside to inside? Do you have a water regulator installed inside the house?

Comment: Was the inside pressure ever good? Did it become bad right after you removed the WS?

Comment: [This Answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/7450/33) might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the water pressure in my home clearly less than my neighbors?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/why-is-the-water-pressure-in-my-home-clearly-less-than-my-neighbors)

Comment: Doesn't seem like a duplicate of that question to me...  Not exactly...  My first question is, are you on a "city water supply" or do you run a private well & pump?

Answer (score 2):

If you removed an old water softener it is likely you knocked loose some crud in the lines that has now moved through the pipes to your faucet.  Take off the screen at the faucet tap and clean it out.  It might not be the source of your problem but it's an easy item to check before calling a plumber.